# How to get the client PC name?

Tags: spring, jsp, authorization

In my project, I want to get the PC name of the client user 
but the methods I am using just give me the PC name of the server:

```
System.get(user.name)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry you can't directly

Your best bet is User-Agent header. You can get it like this in JSP or Servlet,

```
String userAgent = request.getHeader("User-Agent");
```

The header looks like this,

```
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.5; en-US; rv:1.9.0.13) Gecko/2009073021 Firefox/3.0.13
```

It provides detailed information on browser. However, it's pretty much free format so it's very hard to decipher every single one. You just need to figure out which browsers you will support and write parser for each one. When you try to identify the version of browser, always check newer version first. For example, IE6 user-agent may contain IE5 for backward compatibility. If you check IE5 first, IE6 will be categorized as IE5 also.

You can get a full list of all user-agent values from this web site,

http://www.user-agents.org/

With User-Agent, you can tell the exact version of the browser. You can get a pretty good idea on OS but you may not be able to distinguish between different versions of the same OS, for example, Windows NT and 2000 may use same User-Agent.

Remember the scope the client could be behind a proxy

A smart idea is to use javascript and send infos via ajax call

Browser, Operating System, Screen Colors, Screen Resolution, Flash version, and Java Support should all be detectable from JavaScript (and maybe a few more). However, computer name is not possible across all browser at least.

You can do it with IE 'sometimes' as I have done this for an internal application on an intranet which is IE only. Try the following:

```
function GetComputerName()
{
    try
    {
        var network = new ActiveXObject('WScript.Network');
        // Show a pop up if it works
        alert(network.computerName);
    }
    catch (e) { }
}
```